# How to spin a x86_64 ubuntu on Apple M1 with Multipass

Tags: arm64, multipass

I have an Apple M1 processor (ARM64). Is there any way to spin a x86_64 machine? By default Multipass 1.8.0 is launching ARM64 Ubuntu instances.

Comment: See the Multipass M1 Release Candidate announcement: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/announcing-the-first-release-candidate-for-apple-m1-support/24445 . It's in testing, so you are agreeing to report bugs and rough edges!

Comment: This issue is also being tracked [here on GitHub](https://github.com/canonical/multipass/issues/886).

Answer (score 4):

lima https://github.com/lima-vm/lima is the only project that I know that allows you to run x86_64 on M1

Answer (score 3):

Currently, you cannot.

The [discussion](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/announcing-the-first-release-candidate-for-apple-m1-support/24445/12) `@user535733` links to has (Nov '21):

> We’re looking into cross-architecture runs for the future, but it’s not going to happen very soon.
> You could try and build qemu upstream, though - you need `qemu-x86_64-static`.

The QEMU use at the moment (Apr 2022) is about being able to run ARM binaries on x86_64 hardware, not the other way round.